# Adding implementation to Promise.resolve

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I want to create a small script to check model is valid or not via using `isValid` method instead of `then` method.

Here is the script using `then` method:

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  let model = Promise.resolve({
    then(x, y) {
      let isValid = $('input[type=text]').val().length > 0;
      x(isValid);
    }
  });
  
  model.then(isValid => console.log(isValid));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
<button>check</button>
```

My goal:

```
if (model.isValid()) {
    console.log('model is valid.');
}
```

I've tried:

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  let model = Promise.resolve({
    isValid() {
      let isValid = $('input[type=text]').val().length > 0;
      return isValid;
    }
  });
  
  if (model.isValid()) {
    console.log('model is valid.');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
<button>check</button>
```

Error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: 'model.isValid' is not a function

My question: how can I define `isValid` function in this case?

Comment: You need to do that check inside the resolving function!

Comment: It's not clear why you are using a Promise. Is there any asynchronous validation that you didn't paste in your question?

Comment: @Sergeon Because I'm learning Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You second implementation get that runtime error because [Promise.resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) returns:

> a Promise object that is
>   resolved with the given value. If the value is a thenable (i.e. has a
>   "then" method), the returned promise will "follow" that thenable,
>   adopting its eventual state; otherwise the returned promise will be
>   fulfilled with the value.

So, if you define promise like that:

```
 Promise.resolve({
    isValid() {
      let isValid = $('input[type=text]').val().length > 0;
      return isValid;
    }
  });
```

You are returning an object that is **not** *thenable* (it has not a `then` method, but a `isValid` one), so you cannot simply do `model.isValid()` but you have to:

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  let model = Promise.resolve({
    isValid() {
      let isValid = $('input[type=text]').val().length > 0;
      return isValid;
    }
  });
  
  model.then(res => {
      if (res.isValid()) {
        console.log('model is valid.');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
<button>check</button>
```

Comment: Ah. I understand you mean. I cannot use `isValid` method without `then` method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, why do you need use Promise? For your example its more simple

```
$('button').click(function () {
  let isValid = $('input[type=text]').val().length > 0;
  if (isValid) {
     console.log('model is valid.');
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but can you tell me why I was getting the error message? `model.isValid is not a function`